# How to get an address back from the google maps app?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, android-maps

so google maps intent can take in coordinates/address and take you there within the google maps app, but my question is, is there a way to retrieve an address from Google maps app, which I can use in my app.

Example: I start an intent to Google maps. I select a McDonalds in Seattle. How do I get the address of that McDonalds WITHOUT writing my own Maps Activity?

Google developers has put the exact opposite of what I want to do: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents

Hope you guys can help

Comment: I thing no . The Reason is via intent you can just open a another app in multiple context like for sharing or showing location i.e you can give input . to get an output or result back, android provide startActivityForResult() but it will not work as the other application whether it is google maps or something else, not gonna return anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to look into Places API for Android. This API has a PlacePicker dialog, the UI where the user can select a place and obtain all related information.

Please have a look at this page to get more information:

https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker

Hope it helps!